# Как парсить на питоне через websockets? Хочу научиться парсить Bet365

Tags: python, парсер, websocket, websokets

Пришла пора парсить Bet365. Хочу это делать на питоне. Выяснилось что через request парсить не получится, сайт работает на websocket. Не могу найти ни документации на русском, ни видео подробных, в которых используется указание прокси, юзер-агента и прочего. Буду признателен за любую наводку где можно найти, может даже инфа на английском. Опыта особо нет, только учусь. Но на селениуме принципиально не хочется(

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Библиотека 'requests_html' Простой и интуитивно понятный интерфейс, хорошая скорость, поддержка JavaScript, возможность использовать асинхронный код, а также ряд других возможностей